# How to enable single application logout in CAS?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I have configured CAS(v4.0.0) on Apache Tomcat and have multiple clients based on Java, Python and PHP.
What I want to achieve is when I logout from any one application and gets redirected to cas/logout, I want a **popup** to be opened with all the applications that particular user is logged in with and asks whether you want to log out from every application or not.
I am following the official documentation
http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html
and found out Single Logout Per Service which allows me to control single logout behavior individually and I can control whether to allow a particular service to use Back Channel or Front Channel or turned off for that application but what I want to achieve is this -

1.Logging out all applications both from CAS and from browser dynamically on button click

2.Logging out a single application from CAS dynamically on button click, with all other applications having their sessions maintained on CAS server and on browser too.

3.Configuration to be changed in PHP and Python clients to handle the logout callback from CAS server.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Logging out all applications both from CAS and from browser dynamically on button click

invoke /cas/logout. If SLO is turned on, all applications will receive a notification to logout. CAS will logout as well.

> Logging out a single application from CAS dynamically on button click, with all other applications having their sessions maintained on CAS server and on browser too.

Well, you go to your application and you log out from the application. Why do you want to involve CAS? CAS is not responsible for maintaining your app and how it works. /app/logout should do the job.

> Configuration to be changed in PHP and Python clients to handle the logout callback from CAS server.

You'll need to figure out if your clients support CAS SLO. If they do, they will proceed the SLO notification and kill the app session.

Comment: Regarding point 2  

_Well, you go to your application and you log out from the application. Why do you want to involve CAS? CAS is not responsible for maintaining your app and how it works. /app/logout should do the job._  

**Since the session is maintained at CAS server, so logging out an application /app/logout won't work because as soon as you refresh the page the application will be logged in again without entering credentials  as the application session is still logged in at CAS server**

Comment: How can I get a list of applications currently logged in for a particular user after user clicks on logout in an application means does CAS maintains/stores application specific session details for a user and if not then how to achieve it?